# Jdeveloper error (self extraction failed) error while installing Jdeveloper

Tags: oracle, installation, jdeveloper

I downloaded Jdeveloper. After double clicking on .exe file, it opens a popup window, and after that command window opens and gives the error as shown in picture- https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TT0p.png

what i tried-

1. unzip the other folder. (not worked)

2.changed the directory name this folder (not worked)

3. reinstalled Jdeveloper(not worked)

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank You.

Edit-
Content inside log-

```
2022-05-17 08:05:40,586 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Launcher log file is C:\Users\absasahu\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2022-05-17_08-05-40AM\launcher2022-05-17_08-05-40AM.log.
2022-05-17 08:05:40,590 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher - Running jar: C:\Users\absasahu\AppData\Local\Temp\sfxAB7D.tmp\Disk1\install\modules\com.oracle.cie.ora-launcher_12.8.4.0.jar
2022-05-17 08:05:40,595 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting the installer . . .
2022-05-17 08:05:40,596 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher - 
The jar file C:\Users\absasahu\Downloads\oracle Jdeveloper\V998593-01-2.zip needed for this installer is missing.
2022-05-17 08:05:41,613 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher - Self extraction to C:\Users\absasahu\AppData\Local\Temp\sfxAB7D.tmp failed.
2022-05-17 08:05:41,614 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - The log is located here: C:\Users\absasahu\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2022-05-17_08-05-40AM\launcher2022-05-17_08-05-40AM.log.
2022-05-17 08:06:29,695 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher - Exiting launcher, result: 1
```

Edit 2-
renamed the zip file as same as exe file. Then following error is coming.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUY4d.png

Comment: And what is the content of the log file mentioned?

Comment: Updated as edit in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah , My query is solved.

Step 1. first make both of the files names as same like here-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB91j.png

Step 2. Then Run your exe file as administrator by right clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux OS ,After Extracting The Zip Files Leave The Zip Files In The Software Path, Presence Of Compressed Files Is Necessary For Installation Procedure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).